# Green pixels around label's text

Tags: c#, winforms

I turned the BackColor of the `Form` into `Green` and then the `TransparencyKey` into the `BackColor` (that would turn the background color of the WF into Transparent)

```
this.BackColor = Color.Green;
this.TransparencyKey = BackColor;
```

But when I run the project the label I got on the upper left-corner has a pixeled outline of color green...

[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried turning the label's `BackColor` into `Green` hoping that it will turn the pixels transparent... but that didn't happened.

Also I got an image with transparent background (.png with transparent background) and that image got the pixels too. Also tried chaning the BackColor from green to lime but that did nothing but worsening the situation (more pixels than before)...

Anyone out there know how to remove those green pixels?

Comment: These are anti-aliasing pixels and as you can't turn off aa for a control you can't avoid them. What you ca do is do is drawing the texts on the Labels or away with the Labels and draw onto the form or whatever the parent is. Now you can chose graphics properties that avoid aa..

Comment: You can take a screenshot of the Screen area represented by `Rectangle rect = this.RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle);` (since the Form is transparent, you'll take a screenshot of what's under it). Generate a Bitmap of `rect` dimensions and use `Graphics.CopyFromScreen()` to fill it, paint the string(s) on it and then draw it on the Form's surface. You cannot use doublebuffering, so it's not easy to get it right, since when you move the Form you have to invalidate it and flickering is there waiting for you (the FPS is ~24-26 this way). But the text will always render perfectly :)

Comment: @Jimi I'm trying to use the `Graphics.CopyFromScreen()` but Visual Studio gives me an error which is something like: An object reference is required for the property, method or non-static field 'Graphics.CopyFromScreen (int, int, int, int, Size)' ...

Comment: The Graphics object is of course derived from a Bitmap, here. Something like: `var rect = this.RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle); using (var bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height)) using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) { g.CopyFromScreen(rect.Location, Point.Empty, rect.Size); e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, Point.Empty); }`. Now, you could paint this Bitmap in the Paint handler, but you should actually override WndProc, trap `WM_PAINT` and another couple of messages...: *not easy to get it right*.